# GetMessage doesn't want to call WndProc

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to make a window for DirectX, but for some reason, when the window is created, it can't be closed after pressing X and it becomes a zombie process. I found that the GetMessage loop did not call WndProc at all after pressing X. I tried to find a solution, but unsuccessfully, so I want to ask the community. Please advise me.

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int 
nCmdShow)
{
    //register windows class
    const wchar_t* pClassName = L"Senko Interaction";
    WNDCLASSEX wc = { 0 };
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = nullptr;
    wc.hCursor = nullptr;
    wc.hbrBackground = nullptr;
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wc.lpszClassName = pClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = nullptr;

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    //create window instance
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        pClassName,
        L"Senko Interaction",
        WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU,
        0, 0, 1280, 720,
        nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr
        );

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);

    //create message loop
    MSG msg;
    BOOL gResult;
    while ((gResult = GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) > 0)
    {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    if (gResult == -1)
    {
        return -1; //return -1
    }
    else
    {
        return msg.wParam; //return 0
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(1);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam); //return 1
}
```

Comment: On an unrelated note: see [When will GetMessage return -1?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130322-00/?p=4873) So in your case, the answer is: NEVER

Comment: wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;

Answer (score 4):

You set your window class to use `DefWindowProc()` instead of `WndProc()` for the `lpfnWndProc`, so it makes sense why `WndProc()` is never called:

```
wc.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc; // WRONG
```

That should be:

```
wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc; // CORRECT
```